# Comment nommer/décrire le « spiky hair » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, coiffure

J'ai à l'esprit une coiffure plutôt générique, le *[spiky](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spiky) hair* (les « cheveux *spikés* »), avec les [pointes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spike) vers le haut, que ce soit naturellement vu la coupe (brosse etc.) ou coiffés de cette manière.

Quel(s) terme(s) emploie-t-on généralement pour la nommer ou décrire ?

[image]
<sup><sup>détail d'une image : [Tom Chilton - Flickr - exford](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tom_Chilton_-_Flickr_-_exfordy.jpg), auteur Kobac, cc a 2.0, Wikimedia Commons</sup></sup>

Comment: Quelle est la question ?

Comment: En coiffure on parle de cheveux hérissés. Voir la coiffure de [Gabriel Macht](https://www.schwarzkopf.fr/fr/coiffure-cheveux/hommes/les-cheveux-herisses.html) sur ce site de coiffure. P.S. Une coupe en brosse ne peut pas être qualifiée de « naturelle », du moment que les cheveux ont été travaillés de cette façon, ce n'est plus naturel.

Comment: @None D'accord, svp verser ça dans une réponse. J'ai regardé [ici](https://www.elle.fr/Beaute/Cheveux/Coiffure/Meilleurs-salons-de-coiffure-paris) mais ce n'est pas là que je vais parfaire mon vocabulaire sur le sujet qui est plus simple. Oui, la brosse, la nuance c'était davantage entre qui prend cette forme à cause de la coupe par opposition à coiffé ainsi à partir d'un état qui n'est pas du tout _hérissé_ au départ. Ça pourrait faire l'objet d'une question supplémentaire.

Comment: La coiffure hérissée ne part pas de la brosse. Le style hérissé demande des cheveux plus longs que la brosse. [Comment hérisser ses cheveux](https://fr.m.wikihow.com/h%C3%A9risser-ses-cheveux). Et par ailleurs je ne fais plus de réponses...

Comment: Je ne l'affirme pas, la brosse donne un aspect hérissé mais pas comme dans l'image de la question ni celle de ton lien en effet. Dommage. @None

Comment: I'm going to try to edit my answer tomorrow to acknowledge (& confirm) @None 's comment about "hérissé" and how "pic" should be plural, if at all. (We do lose an hour of sleep here tonight, however, so I might be struggling even more than usual!) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bart Simpson a ce que j'appellerais du "spiky/spiked hair" et [ce *fr.wikipedia.com* article  sur son créateur, Matt Groening](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Groening#Les_courts-m%C3%A9trages_du_Tracey_Ullman_Show) mentionne que:

> Dans les premiers courts-métrages des Simpson, Bart a **les cheveux** plus
>   **pointus** et ses **pics** sont tous de tailles différentes. Plus tard, le
>   nombre de **pics** est fixé à neuf et ils sont tous de même taille.

Et selon utilisateur ["christian6881" de *jeuxvideo.com*](http://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/1-28259-257561-1-0-1-0-jeu-qui-est-ce.htm):

> [Pour] décrire une personne exemple Bart Simpson, on dit **cheveux en
>   pic**, t-shirt orange etc.

Je ne suis ni français ni coiffeur, mais j'aime *Les Simpsons* et comme "christian 6881," je voterais pour **cheveux en pic**.

---

**Cautionary addendum** to acknowledge that "User None's" comment to my answer (which comment is pasted below) is probably correct in all respects:

> « Pic » est un terme à connotation négative en coiffure. Le « pic »
>   est la mèche récalcitrante qu'on n'arrive pas à coiffer comme on veut
>   parce qu'elle se redresse tout le temps. S'il y a plusieurs de ces
>   mèches en français on devrait d'ailleurs dire « en pics », pluriel,
>   pour la photo de la question. La photo montre une coiffure tout à fait
>   structurée avec des cheveux « hérissés », tout à fait semblable à
>   celle de Gabriel Macht ... . [link to Mr. Macht's look omitted]

Although I would translate a recalcitrant lock of hair or "cowlick" as a "touffe" or "h[o]uppe," I have no reason to doubt that "pic" is another, perhaps the best, way to render "cowlick" in French and therefore, you might not want to use the negative "pic" in the context at issue.

Regardless, the "pic" in my suggestion of "cheveux en pic" should be pluralized to be "cheveux en pics" or perhaps even as ["cheveux en piques"](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/spiked-hair.460788/), as suggested by *wordreference* user "pieanne" and later by user "Zhorg" in the linked *wordreference* discussion of "spiked (hair)."

In that *wordreference* discussion, I must admit that I am the most impressed by the answer offered by user "tilt" ("Elle avait les cheveux brillants et hérissés, peut-être ?"), not so much by the answer itself, but by his/her follow-up comment in response to user "the_citron's" suggestion of "cheveux en hérisson", which indicates to me that "tilt" gave this issue some real thought, to-wit:

> C'est amusant, pour ma part, je dirais bien plus volontiers hérissés
>   que en hérisson, et en pointes plutôt que pointus ! Et en l'absence de
>   certitude sur l'aspect véritable de la coiffure, hérissé me semble
>   plus générique que en pointes. Hence my suggestion

All that to say (unfortunately in English, because I'm already in far enough over my head trying to discuss hairdos in English!) that **"cheveux hérissés"** is probably the correct term.

---

Finally, although perhaps relevant here, I won't even try to address the possible nuance mentioned in the last comment/question (by user "OLN") in the *wordreference* discussion:

> "Le sens [de "**spiked hair**"] est-il différente de celui de **spiky hair** qui a été discuté
>   auparavant ?
>    Liens [ici](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/spiky)"

Comment: « Pic » est un terme à connotation négative en coiffure. Le « pic » est la mèche récalcitrante qu'on n'arrive pas à coiffer comme on veut parce qu'elle se redresse tout le temps. S'il y a plusieurs de ces mèches en français on devrait d'ailleurs dire « en pics », pluriel, pour la photo de la question. La photo montre une coiffure tout à fait structurée avec des cheveux « hérissés », tout à fait semblable à celle de [Gabriel Macht ici](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBvUVyo6Mw4).

Comment: Merci d'avoir rassemblé toute l'information dans la réponse, pour des gens qui s'y connaissent peu on aura quand même fait une bonne _job_, avec l'aide de _none_. je mettrais en gras _cheveux hérissés_ dans le para. avant la ligne. Let me tell you my Walmart joke. I go there wanting to buy a _napperon_ but the clerk ends up speaking English and for the love of G. I can't remember something like _placemat_ and there's this weird interference wtih _apron_ so she ended up thinking I was looking for a bib something. In my youth I would have been completely humiliated really. But I don't give a sh.

Comment: ...no more about what people think of me lolll. So anyways, cheers!

Comment: @enfernette Merci! Oui, la reponse correcte, meme si elle n'etait pas mon idee, doit etre en gras, et c'est fait. Drole d'histoire  chez Wallymart! Et c'est vrai, je remarque que plus que les gens croient que j'ai besoin des "bibs" plus que je m'en fous du reste! Thanks again.